# Magento reindex Category Flat Data not working

Tags: mysql, magento

Having finally got a local version of our client's Magento site working I've now been able to get a bit closer to fixing their problem. We are unable to reindex the Category Flat Data.

Looking at the logs there's an issue with creating a foreign key when the reindexing takes place, and this wipes out the mage_catalog_category_flat_store_1 table causing the entire site to break.

However, I'm not quite sure why the foreign key can't be created, as the db user has full access rights. The log file contains the following:

```
2015-02-10T14:38:27+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
Trace: #0 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\lib\Zend\Db\Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `m...', Array)
#4 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('CREATE TABLE `m...', Array)
#5 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(2039): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('CREATE TABLE `m...')
#6 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\Flat.php(604): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->createTable(Object(Varien_Db_Ddl_Table))
#7 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\Flat.php(1418): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->_createTable('1')
#8 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\Flat.php(1431): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->_createTables()
#9 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Category\Indexer\Flat.php(246): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Flat->reindexAll()
#10 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Process.php(209): Mage_Catalog_Model_Category_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#11 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\app\code\core\Mage\Index\Model\Process.php(255): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\app\code\core\Mage\Index\controllers\Adminhtml\ProcessController.php(124): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(419): Mage_Index_Adminhtml_ProcessController->reindexProcessAction()
#14 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('reindexProcess')
#15 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 Z:\XAMPP\htdocs\sites\Providore\index.php(90): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
```

Can anyone explain what I need to do to get the reindexing to work? Until we can get this working the categories in the back-end of the site don't match the categories in the nav on the front-end of the site.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable flat tables:

```
System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend 
Disable Use Flat Catalog Category and Use Flat Catalog Product.
```

Truncate your flat table.

It should work fine now, without flat. Now you can enable flat again, and reindex to build it up.

Comment: Brilliant, seems to have done the trick on the local version of the site - just need to implement on live :)

Comment: flat category and flat catalog are both created on the fly, so there is really no worries to truncate or even delete them. But take care all _flat_ are not part of that process and `sales_flat_order` is, off course, something you don't want to see empty.

Comment: For some odd reason it didn't work on the live site - the first catalog won't created I get errno:150 and a trace (which is too big to add here!)